# EF trying to insert nulls into database for some unknown reason

Tags: c#, .net

For some reason, this piece of code returns the following exception:

```
An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 
Inner Exception: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', 
table 'aspnet-Webate.dbo.Tasks'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\n
The statement has been terminated
```

the variable tasks is a string with this form:

```
(task1, task2, task3, task4)
```

The diagnostics are showing each of those 4 tasks with no problems in the console. none of the array indexes are null or blank

```
            string[] taskArr = null;
            tasks = tasks.Substring(1, tasks.Length - 2); //remove the starting and ending parenthesis
            tasks = tasks.ToLower();
            tasks = tasks.Replace(" ", "");
            taskArr = tasks.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            foreach (string t in taskArr)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("t="+t);
                if (t != null && t != "")
                {
                    Task task = db.Tasks.Find(t);
                    if (task == null)
                    {
                        task = new Task { Id = t };
                        db.Tasks.Add(task);
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges(); //save task changes before trying to save role
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw exception code
            }
```

Is there any other explanation for why EntityFramework may be trying to insert nulls into the database?

Here is the task model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

This class is generated by ADO.NET Entity Data Model functionality of Visual Studio 2012, and there are no other partial implementations of it

Comment: It throws an error because you have not given a value for the column `ID`. Is it a primary key? Did you define it as an Identity column?

Comment: the answer is yes to both of your questions, as for not giving a value, look at the line:  task = new Task{ Id = t };

Comment: where did you set its configuration? via data annotation or fluentApi?

Comment: You mean where the data model is defined? in an ADO.NET Entity Data Model. db.Tasks references the Tasks table that has a many-many relationship with another table. other than that relationship, Tasks only have that one primary key.

Comment: Do you mind posting your Task model?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the Task model

Comment: Does IntelliTrace show the generated query when debugging?

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio Ultimate :(, no IntelliTrace. Is there another way I can view the insert statement? On another note, it's complaining that I'm trying to insert nulls into the database. it's a pretty good bet the insert statement is indeed receiving nulls from EntityFramework. I'm trying to find out why this could be.

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed, the problem was that the Id property had StoreGeneratedPattern set to Identity, which causes it to auto-increment the primary key. since the Primary key is a string, you can't really auto-increment that :). and the additional effect of this setting appears to be that it ignored any set; commands on the Id column since it was planning to auto-increment it anyway.

Thanks for all of your support